# Is there a ruby parser for IFC ISO-10303-21 files (STEP-files)?

Tags: ruby, wavefront, ifc, step

I'm looking for a [STEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_10303-21) file parser for ruby that will spit out [OBJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) files or a model structure similar to [OBJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) files.

I also have found a make your own parser gem [here](https://github.com/chriswailes/RLTK) but not quite sure how to properly set up the parser / lexer rules to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is of any help, but I stumbled across the same problem a year ago. I had to get an IFC parser for C#. Although there are several solutions already, I decided so create my own. Therefore, I had to do the following:

1. Write a program (Generator), which reads an EXPRESS Schema (this EXPRESS file contains all the entities of the current IFC release defining their properties and the inheritance hierarchy) and creates all these entities as C# classes
2. This Generator further has to fit every so created class with the ability to write its objects to a STEP string
3. Put all the finished entities in a class library and use it in your main code
4. I also included an additional class in this class library, which can read IFC-files and then creates all the respective objects (this was really hard to do and I was not 100% successful, so it only works for certain classes for me. However, that was enough for my purpose)

[image: Showing the workflow of my program]

So I reckon you could follow the same path just doing everything in Ruby. I hope this helped a little. Don't hesitate to ask, if you got any more questions.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I was hoping to avoid building it out myself but if it does turn out to be the only way then I guess I have no choice.

Answer (score 0):

I use late binding SDAI since I believe early binding (generation of C++/C# classes corresponding to STEP Entities) is not true way. I deal with AP242, AP209, AP238 (some problems were encountered, but I hope to resolve these problem), IFC. So, late binding is better way.